# Why is the "uniqueness of the composition" shown differently despite having the same steps as in proving the "existence of the composition"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading about the *Transplanting Theorem* from *Modern Algebra* by *Seth Werner* which states that there exists a unique composition $\nabla$ for a bijective function from set $E$ onto set $F$ such that $(E,\Delta)\cong (F,\nabla)$ and defined by $$\forall x,y \in F~~~ x\nabla y =  f\left(f^\leftarrow(x)~\Delta ~f^\leftarrow(y) \right)\,.$$

Then I checked [$\mathsf{Pr}\infty\mathsf{fWiki} $](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Transplanting_Theorem), which divides the proof in **existence** and **uniqueness** of the composition as in the following :

> ### Existence
>
> To show $\oplus$ as defined above exists:
>
> [...] \begin{align} f \left({u \circ v}\right) & = f \left({f^{-1} \left({x}\right) \circ f^{-1} \left({y}\right)}\right)\\ &= f \left({f^{-1} \left({x}\right)}\right) \oplus f \left({f^{-1} \left({y}\right)}\right)\\ &=  x \oplus y\\ &=f \left({u}\right) \oplus  f \left({v}\right) \end{align}

It is seen that $f$ is an isomorphism as required.

So far so good. Quite an easy proof.

> ### Uniqueness
>
> Let $f$ be the isomorphism whose existence has been proven above.
>
> \begin{align}f \left({f^{-1} \left({x}\right) \circ f^{-1} \left({y}\right)}\right) & =  f \left({f^{-1} \left({x}\right)}\right) \oplus f \left({f^{-1} \left({y}\right)}\right)\\ &=\left({f \circ f^{-1} \left({x}\right)}\right) \oplus \left({f \circ f^{-1} \left({y}\right)}\right)\\ &=  \left({I_T \left({x}\right)}\right) \oplus \left({I_T \left({y}\right)}\right) \\ &= x \oplus y\end{align} ...

I couldn't get how the proof of **uniqueness** is different from that of **existence**. The steps are more or less same. But still the second one is **uniqueness** and the first one is **existence**.

I'm unable to visualise how re-iterating the same steps with additional steps of using the definition of composition and the property of bijection having left and right inverse.

Could anyone tell me how the more or less same steps in the second one proves the **uniqueness**?

Comment: This is actually very common. If you look at the ProofWiki page, on the side there are arguments that justify the given identities; you can see for yourself that those are quite different. Of course, when you want to prove that some operation exists uniquely, it shouldn't be that much surprising that the actual operation and, say, anoter candidate for the operation, should satisfy the same identities. The trick is to justify them in each case.

Comment: The steps are similar because you deal with the same object of sort and the key is "It's a homomorphism" kind of function. As such the steps will look somewhat the same but in the first one, you prove it is a homomorphism and in the latter you show any two such will be the same.

Comment: Okay thanks @ZelosMalum; I would love to see this as an answer if you have time to jot it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they look the same is because ultimately you deal with a specific type of object. Namely a homomorphism. Finding a set function that satisfy what we want is most often a trivial thing, with axiom of choice and all such. So the existence criteria is more to show that there exist such a function that is a homomorphism.

When you prove uniqueness you prove again that any two functions that are homomorphisms will map objects to the same object. They do look very similar to each other however because they must be homomorphisms. So the steps that can be done are that of a homomorphism.